# The bash script in mac automator works for texts in Chrome, but not in Safari

Tags: mac, safari, bash, automator, google-chrome

Here is the code:

```
if [ "$@" != "" ]; then
    timestamp="$(date +%Y-%m-%d' '%H:%M:%S)"
    dictlink="dict://$(echo $@ | sed 's/ /%20/')"
    ahref="<A HREF=\"$dictlink\">$@</A>"
        
    echo "$timestamp - $ahref</br>" >> /Users/username/Documents/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.html

    open /Users/username/Documents/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.html

fi
```

It stored the selected word into a HTML and opens it to verify. In Chrome, it works fine. In Safari, it still opens the HTML, however the echo seems not work, nothing there.

Comment: Does Safari have Full Disk Access (or at least access to Documents)? One way to force this would be to temporarily set the Downloads destination to Documents and download something.

Comment: If this doesn't help: How are you running the script from Safari?

Comment: It's still not working..

Comment: What does "still" mean, what have you changed? We can't see on your screen or know what you have done, without sharing details it's impossible to help you.